# Find Date variable within a row and return Column VBA

Tags: vba, excel, find

I am looking to find a variable within a row and return the column reference. The code I have written so far is;

```
Dim VarianceDate As String
VarianceDate = Sheets("Summary").Range("C12").Value


Rows("6").Find(What:=VarianceDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
      , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

TargetCol = ActiveCell.Column
```

In this example the Variance date is 01/06/2015, however when I stepinto the code in VBA it returns nothing. Except When I search for it manually It finds the correct cell.

Eventually I would like to use the TargetCol reference to help me extract the correct data into another workbook.

Any help would be much appreicated.

Thanks

Comment: You're saying that `VarianceDate` = nothing?  Could you try a line like: `Debug.Print VarianceDate` to confirm this?  If so, you'd need to make sure that your sheet and range references are correct.

Comment: Nope, the variancedate = 01/06/2015 I think the issue lies within the "Find" part of the code. As this returns nothing i.e. it does not carry out any action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention that the search term is a date and also if the activecell is not in your find range, it will throw an error due to the inclusion of After:=ActiveCell

Try the following code

```
Sub FindDateCol()

    Dim VarianceDate As String: VarianceDate = Sheets("Summary").Range("C12").Value

    Dim TargetCell As Range, TargetCol As Integer
    Set TargetCell = Rows("6").Find(What:=CDate(VarianceDate), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not TargetCell Is Nothing Then TargetCol = TargetCell.Column

    MsgBox TargetCol

End Sub
```

Comment: This code won't return the desired result since the `ActiveCell` will currently be whichever cell was selected before the code ran. As a general rule, I'd stay away from using `ActiveCell`. Instead just say `Msgbox TargetCell.Column`.

Comment: Yes - copy and paste error. I don't normally use ActiveCell either. Thanks for the typo spot