# Find returns nothing even if value exists

Tags: excel, vba

So here I have the nth question about the find method. I have read many questions about it and the  problems it carries, but still couldnt find a solution to my problem.

I simply want to return the number of row and number of column for a particular value (a date). However, the code runs always the same 91 error (object variable not set) because the find method does not find anything.

I have tried to define the variable as range and change the code by setting the variable (i.e. set daterow = etc.). But the problem persists.

```
Sub actual_cash_flow()
Dim cfdate As Long
Dim today As Long
Dim daterow As Long
Dim datecolumn As Long

today = Date
cfdate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(today, -1)

daterow = Sheet2.Cells.Find(What:=cfdate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False).Row
datecolumn = Sheet2.Cells.Find(What:=cfdate).Column


End Sub
```

I would like to have number of row and number of column in order to identify the cell and then perform some actions.

**EDIT:**

By editing the code as suggested by @mikku and by debugging the range where there is the value and the variable defined in the code I get the same value, however, I still get nothing as output. So I really dont know where the error is. See the image.

[image]

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838292/7599798

Comment: You are looking for a date but you have declared `cfdate as **Long**`

Comment: declaring the cfdate as date returns the same error

Comment: Check date format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186598/find-date-variable-within-a-row-and-return-column-vba/31188450#31188450

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Can you upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some sharing site and post a link here?  Are your Windows Regional Short Date settings `dd-MMM-yy`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld here you are [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4f45c99c9bd0de3c4cc53baea656f56920190710123246/0dafde24b438b086d576ac121ba263a020190710123246/1ba131). Yes, the format date is as you have written in your comment

Comment: @RonRosenfeld however i would like that the find methods works for all formats, not only for a specific one

Comment: After looking at your worksheet, I believe your question is a duplicate of [Excel VBA Range.Find Date That is a Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula).  My answer explains the issue, and also provides two work-arounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in my answer to a previous question, working with dates and the `Range.Find` function can be tricky.  One of the reasons seems to be that the VBA Date datatype is not the same as the date stored on an Excel worksheet.  The latter is a `Double` formatted to look like a date.

So, especially if you want your `.Find` method to be independent of the date settings, you are probably best off not using the `Range.Find` method but rather looping through the data.

In the code below, I show an example of how this might work, making assumptions based on the workbook you provided, and also using a VBA array as this will run much faster than looping through a range on the worksheet:

```
Sub actualcf()

Dim cfdate As Long  'Yes --Long for this application
Dim daterow As Long
Dim datecolumn As Long
Dim fnd As Range

Dim srchRng As Range
Dim vSrch As Variant
Dim I As Long

With Worksheets("Peschiera CF")

'Find the row with the dates
Set srchRng = .Cells.Find(what:="Yr. Ending", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues)

'Read that row into a VBA array, but only the columns with data
'Note that we are using `.Value2` which has no formatting
If Not srchRng Is Nothing Then
    vSrch = .Range(.Cells(srchRng.Row, 1), .Cells(srchRng.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value2
End If

cfdate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1)
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrch, 2)
    If vSrch(1, I) = cfdate Then
        daterow = srchRng.Row
        datecolumn = I
    End If
Next I

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
Sub actual_cash_flow()

Dim cfdate As Date
Dim daterow As Long
Dim datecolumn As Long
Dim fnd As Range

cfdate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1)

Set fnd = Worksheets("SheetName").Cells.Find(What:=cfdate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)

If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

    daterow = fnd.Row
    datecolumn = fnd.Column

End If

End Sub
```

***Put in your sheet Name in the Code.***

The problem was with the setup of variables, you should declare them as date when searching for a Date.

Comment: nope. It returns nothing. If I search the variable in excel as 30-Jun-19 then it finds it, so there must be a problem with the code.

Comment: "dd-mmm-yy" so 30 june 2019 is 30-Jun-19

Comment: You need to share your workbook, otherwise I don't see why it isn't working

Comment: here you are [sample](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4f45c99c9bd0de3c4cc53baea656f56920190710123246/0dafde24b438b086d576ac121ba263a020190710123246/1ba131)